# Videos in Vue SPA not autoplaying/loading on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, vue.js, video

I have a simple video portfolio site that I built in vue. The Video player dynamically loads a video and then plays it via Javascript

Vue template code for player:

```
 <video @click.stop :class="$style.playingVideo" ref="theVideo" src="" controls preload></video>
```

And this is my mounted code in the component to set the video source and then play it once it can:

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.$refs.theVideo.src = this.getVideoUrl(this.videoName);
    if (
      this.$refs.theVideo.readyState >= this.$refs.theVideo.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA
    ) {
      this.$refs.theVideo.play();
    } else {
      this.$refs.theVideo.addEventListener(
        "canplay",
        () => {
          this.$refs.theVideo.play();
        },
        false
      );
    }
```

This works great on Desktop and Android, but on iPhone you have to click on the video again to get it to play. I know iPhone has special playback requirements. But I'm lost on the best way to get them to work with Vue.

The desired behaviour is obviously to load the video as soon as the user clicks it and then autoplays. My idea now is to just make an exception in the javascript for iOS devices and load the videos directly in a new tab when clicked. Is this the best approach for iOS? Or is there a better Vue solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>
> iOS not only prevents autoplay but also preloading the video until the user initiates it.

That's why your eventListener never fires.

Source: https://www.aerserv.com/blog/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/

Comment: great. Thank you. I will try loading the video in a separate tab instead.

Comment: problem also turned out to be due to cloudfront removing the Accept-Ranges: Bytes header for some reason (still investigating)